# Opendistro for Elasticsearch - ISM is not triggering jobs

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-opendistro, ism

I am trying to use ISM with opendistro on AWS Elasticsearch Service v7.8. I am trying to set up a basic rollover/delete policy and it seems that the policy is not triggering. I assume I am doing something wrong, but I can't seem to track it down... I am testing it out using a rollover every hour and a delete after 6 hours...

Here is my ISM policy which I have so appropriately named, "test":

```
{
    "policy": {
        "policy_id": "test",
        "description": "A test policy",
        "last_updated_time": 1605196195481,
        "schema_version": 1,
        "error_notification": null,
        "default_state": "active",
        "states": [{
                "name": "active",
                "actions": [{
                    "rollover": {
                        "min_index_age": "1h"
                    }
                }],
                "transitions": [{
                    "state_name": "delete",
                    "conditions": {
                        "min_index_age": "6h"
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
                "name": "delete",
                "actions": [{
                    "delete": {}
                }],
                "transitions": []
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I've create a template to maintain the index creation etc. Here is the template. Notice I am adding the rollover alias "atest" but the policy_id is "test". I do not add the index to any alias in this template:

```
PUT /_template/atest
{
    "index_patterns" : [
      "atest-*"
    ],
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "opendistro" : {
          "index_state_management" : {
            "policy_id" : "test",
            "rollover_alias" : "atest"
          }
        },
        "analysis" : {
        }
      }
    },
    "mappings" : {
    },
    "aliases" : { }
}
```

I then create an index using the index pattern from template, adding it to what I have defined as the rollover-alias above:

```
PUT /atest-000001
{
  "aliases": {"atest": {}}
}
```

Then I can see the doc in the opendistro-ism-config index:

```
{
  "_index": ".opendistro-ism-config",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "T_k8jMI5RvuWRaLp1tY_hg",
  "_version": 2,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "managed_index": {
      "name": "atest-000001",
      "enabled": true,
      "index": "atest-000001",
      "index_uuid": "T_k8jMI5RvuWRaLp1tY_hg",
      "schedule": {
        "interval": {
          "start_time": 1605200587242,
          "period": 30,
          "unit": "Minutes"
        }
      },
      "last_updated_time": 1605200587242,
      "enabled_time": 1605200587242,
      "policy_id": "test",
      "policy_seq_no": 422,
      "policy_primary_term": 111,
      "policy": {
        "policy_id": "test",
        "description": "A test policy",
        "last_updated_time": 1605196195481,
        "schema_version": 1,
        "error_notification": null,
        "default_state": "active",
        "states": [
          {
            "name": "active",
            "actions": [
              {
                "rollover": {
                  "min_index_age": "1h"
                }
              }
            ],
            "transitions": [
              {
                "state_name": "delete",
                "conditions": {
                  "min_index_age": "6h"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "delete",
            "actions": [
              {
                "delete": {}
              }
            ],
            "transitions": []
          }
        ]
      },
      "change_policy": null
    }
  },
  "fields": {
    "managed_index.last_updated_time": [
      "2020-11-12T17:03:07.242Z"
    ],
    "policy.last_updated_time": [],
    "policy.states.actions.notification.destination.last_update_time": [],
    "policy.error_notification.destination.last_update_time": [],
    "managed_index.schedule.interval.start_time": [
      "2020-11-12T17:03:07.242Z"
    ],
    "managed_index.enabled_time": [
      "2020-11-12T17:03:07.242Z"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1605200587242
  ]
}
```

At some point I see the managed index info go from "initializing" to

```
{
    "message": "Successfully initialized policy: test"
}
```

At this point, nothing happens. The row for "atest-000001" in the ISM console in kibana says the "state" is "active", the "action" is "-" and the "Job Status" is "Running". It will remain like this for days...
I have also tried:

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "persistent": {
    "opendistro.index_state_management.enabled" : true
    
  }
}
```

Still nothing triggers. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was an internal AWS ES thing. Updating to R20201117 resolved the issue.